# Is that possible to download google derive files without integration with ios

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest, download-manager

Is that possible to download files from google drive without integrate it's sdk (class files) or authentication. Consider following scenario:

1. I Used UIWebView in mysample application.
2. I am logged in to Google Drive through UIWebView (Like logged in to google drive same as browser logged in).
3. Now i want to download google drive documents in to mysample application document folder.

Problem:

1. When i am trying to download file from google drive it will now downloaded (I am using nsurl connection or ASIHttpRequest for download file).
2. I Integrate GoogleSDK (Class Library) in another sample application it will work fine and files are downloaded using file.downloadURL.

Now, My simple question is can we download files from google drive by UIWebView logged in or not? Is there any way?

Comment: Does this help you at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730712/download-unpublished-google-spreadsheet-as-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support integrating with the iOS web view, and suggest you use the SDK.