# UIWebView cannot open .doc file properly (overwritten texts)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have ran into a problem. There's this [doc file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6U672prrSTPOTlyUzdGcGZBWDQ/view?usp=sharing) I have encountered which UIWebView is unable to display properly (texts are overwritten). This file looks pretty ok to me as it opens properly in libre office as well as google docs. I tried WKWebView but it has the same result as UIWebView. Issue is observed in simulator as well as device.

Screen shot attached.
[image]

I have other doc files too which are loading properly apart from this one.
Looks like UIWebView cannot handle some special kind of formatting (idk)??

What exactly is the issue here and is there any way to solve it?

**EDIT 1 :** If you are directly loading the url I gave above you need to download the file (by clicking the download button you will see when you load the google drive page otherwise you are basically opening the web page not the actual doc file).

Comment: For me, it is working with the UIWebView, cleanly. I don't see any issue or overlapping, I'm using Xcode 8.3 and iOS 10.3.FYI, http://imgur.com/a/sGZez

Comment: set `webView.scalesPageToFit = YES`?

Comment: @Imad see my edit.

Comment: @Rishab Do you want to download the doc file?

Comment: @Rishab check this, Google developer saying to use SDK instead of UIWebView, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841478/is-that-possible-to-download-google-derive-files-without-integration-with-ios

Comment: Dude the problem is not with google drive. I have uploaded the document to google drive because I am too lazy to search for another file hosting site. I am getting this doc from server and google drive has nothing to do with it. Anyways I filed a bug report https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=32348362. Let's see what happens.